# Php preg_replace space

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to block to use space. Where must i edit and what to write?

```
 $k = "".$post['dname'.$i]."";
                 $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]/", "", $k);
                 $database->setVillageName($database->RemoveXSS($varray[$i]['wref']),$name);
```

Comment: want to block to use space ? explain this

Comment: You are Geek you must know. :) Sorry for my bad English but how can i explain it.. But its solved removed \s

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `\s` from the character class:

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $k);
```

or (shorter):

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^\w-]/", "", $k);
```

**Edit**

```
$k = "".$post['dname'.$i]."";
$name = preg_replace("/[^\w\s-]/", "", $k);
if (preg_match('/^\s+$/', $name) {
    // error : $name mustn't be all spaces
    // do appropriate stuff
}
$database->setVillageName($database->RemoveXSS($varray[$i]['wref']),$name);
```

Comment: @user3351524: `\w` as the same meaning than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and it's shorter to write :-)

Comment: But now i cant use any space. I want to block only one space to use.

Comment: @user3351524: Sorry, I don't get you. Please edit your question and add some examples showing input and output.

Comment: Users can use like that "asd asd qwe    qwe" But i dont want only one space like that " "

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to allow one space in your string, then you could use the `or` operator in a regex.

```
$str = 'some name';

if(preg_match('/^([\w]+|[\w]+ [\w]+)$/', $str, $matches))
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

This code will succeed when there are 0 or 1 spaces in the string. Otherwise it will fail if it has more spaces.

You can play with the code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/yTtWz1

---

A `preg_replace` would of course be similar:

```
preg_replace('/^([\w]+|[\w]+ [\w]+)$/', "", $str)
```